# How to write xpath which have multiple values (two lines) in label

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have tried this,

> //label[text()='Legal Business Nam (you can add a DBA after your
> account is open )']
>
> //label[text()='Legal Business Name' and '(you can add a DBA after
> your account is open )']

but does not work.

[image]

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12"><label>Legal Business Name (you can add a DBA after your account is open )</label><input type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Enter legal business name" name="company_name" maxlength="250" value=""><label id="company_name-error" class="help-block text-danger validation-error" for="company_name"></label></div>
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Let me add HTML code. Done, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `.` instead of `text()`.

`//label[contains(., 'Legal Business Name (you can add a DBA after your account is open )')]`

Or just join 2 `[contains(text(), '')]` statements like this:

```
//label[contains(text(), 'Legal Business Name ')][contains(text(), '(you can add a DBA after your account is open )')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close enough. Instead of `text()` you need to use `contains()` as follows:

```
//label[contains(., 'you can add a DBA after your account is open')]
```

Ideally, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[contains(., 'you can add a DBA after your account is open')]")))
```